# Validando campos JavaScript

Tags: javascript, formulário

Estou com um probleminha em um código que transforma o campo de Telefone para este formato: *(51) 96321-5465*. Porém, toda vez que clico em Enviar, o formulário diz no campo: `"É preciso que o formato corresponda ao exigido.`" e não deixa enviar o formulário, o código é este:

```
<!-- Formatar campo telefone -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Máscaras ER */
function mascara(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
}
function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}
function mtel(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");             //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
    return v;
}
function id( el ){
    return document.getElementById( el );
}
window.onload = function(){
    id('telefone').onkeypress = function(){
        mascara( this, mtel );
    }
}
</script> <!-- FIM Formatar campo telefone -->
```

E onde quero que apareça o campo para informar o telefone:

```
< div class="campo">
    < label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
    < input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Somente números" size="16" maxlength="15"  value="" pattern="[0-9]+$"/>
< /div>
```

Porr que fica aparecendo esta mensagem e não deixa enviar mesmo o campo não possuindo um required?

Comment: Achei que fosse algo com os "size="16" maxlength="15"" mas não é

Comment: Voce esta usando mascara, entao ele indica um formato inapropriado

Comment: Peguei este código de exemplo Rafael, a máscara esta indicando um formato errôneo? como assim? Desculpe, estou iniciando agora em JavaScript

Comment: Remova o atributo `pattern="[0-9]+$"`

Comment: o que voce quer fazer? apenas ter uma mascara no input e verificar se tem numeros suficiente para ser telefone?

Comment: Realmente eé o que o @KaduAmaral falou, eu nao tinha visto o pattern, eé so remover. voce esta usando expressão para validar numeros apenas.

Comment: Muuuuuuuuuuuuuito obrigado pela ajuda pessoal, era só isso, eu havia pensado nisso, porém achei que se removendo-o, ele deixaria adicionar letras e outros caracteres, o que não acontece devido as funções criadas a cima de js, mais uma vez, MUITO OBRIGADO!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando o atributo `pattern` para validar os dados do `input`. Removendo-o tudo ficará certo, e a validação ocorrerá apenas via Javascript:

```
<div class="campo">
    <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
    <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Somente números" size="16" maxlength="15"  value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/mascara-telefonet.htm)

Não é necessário remover o atributo  `pattern` mas sim adequá-lo.

```
(^[\d-\)\(]+$)
```

HTML

```
<div class="campo">
<label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
<input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Somente números" size="16" maxlength="15"  value="" pattern="(^[\d-\)\(]+$)"/>
```

- `\d   dígito  o mesmo que [0-9]`
- `-\)\(  caracteres aceitos`

Comment: Realmente funciona Leo Caracciolo, muito obrigado por sua contribuição, muito grato, tenha uma ótima tarde.