# Validação do campo de telefone com js

Tags: javascript

Eu estou tentando validar o telefone de um formulário pré definido pelo `RD Station` e esta minha regra não está funcionando, alguma dica ou algo que eu esteja fazendo errado?

Segue link do formulário: https://materiais.onsafety.com.br/demonstracao-modulo-de-inspecao/

```
function validaTelefone(){
            var telefone = document.getElementById('personal_phone');
            if (telefone.value.lenght > 17){
                alert('Insira um telefone válido. Ex: (99)99999-9999');
                telefone.focus();
                telefone.value = "";
                return false;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Existem diversas formas.** 
Sugiro que busque as perguntas/respostas já existentes.

- [Validação Campo Telefone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293950/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-campo-telefone)
  [Como validar número de telefone fixo e celular jQuery Validator?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15120/como-validar-n%C3%BAmero-de-telefone-fixo-e-celular-jquery-validator)
- [Como validar telefone celular e residencial?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333754/como-validar-telefone-celular-e-residencial)
- [Expressão Regular em JavaScript para Telefone com DDI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189187/express%C3%A3o-regular-em-javascript-para-telefone-com-ddi)
- [Validando campos JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207115/validando-campos-javascript)

**Uma forma em código:** 
*- separar a string em campos específicos.*

```
 .filter('telefone', function() {
            /*
            Formata numero do telefone como: (xx) xxxx-xxxx ou (xx) xxxxx-xxxx

            */

            return function (number) {
                /*
                @param {Number | String} number - Number that will be formatted as telephone number
                Returns formatted number: (##) ####-#### or (##) #####-####
                    if number.length < 4: ###
                    else if number.length < 7: (###) ###

                */
                if (!number) { return ''; }

                number = String(number);

                // Will return formattedNumber.
                // If phonenumber isn't longer than an area code, just show number
                var formattedNumber = number;

                // if the first character is '1', strip it out and add it back


                var area, front, end;
                if (number.length == 10){
                    // # (##) ####-#### as c (area) front-end
                    area = number.substring(0,2);
                    front = number.substring(2, 6);
                    end = number.substring(6, 10);
                }
                else
                {
                    // # (##) #####-#### as c (area) front-end
                    area = number.substring(0,2);
                    front = number.substring(2, 7);
                    end = number.substring(7, 11);
                }

                if (front) {
                    formattedNumber = ( "(" + area + ") " + front);
                }
                if (end) {
                    formattedNumber += ("-" + end);
                }
                return formattedNumber;
            };
        })
```